# Why is wrapper div shifting downwards?

Tags: html, css

Facing a very unique situation. In the following code, ALL the divs are nested inside one large parent `.wrapper` div. In the `.wrapper` properties, I have clearly defined the positioning (top/left) as `0px` and `0px` margin. But it still is shifting a little downwards, resulting in shifting of the entire page contents downwards and hence leaving a blank space on top.

The background color of site is black. You can see the top image holder div (gray) along with other divs shifted slightly downwards.

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

html,body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  padding: 0px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 725px;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin-left: auto;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
}

.topimage {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 175px;
  background-color: #666;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  border: thin solid #FFF;
}

.topimage img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
}

.menu {
  background: linear-gradient(#0F1A9B, black 100%);
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 50px;
  max-width: 960px;
  position: relative;
  top: 175px;
}

.list {
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  /* [disabled]background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1); */
  padding: 0px;
  width: auto;
  /* [disabled]position: relative; */
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "MS Serif", "New York", serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.list li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 0%;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  /* [disabled]background-color: rgba(0,51,255,1); */
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
  /* [disabled]float: left; */
  line-height: 50px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #0F1A9B;
  position: relative;
  top: 175px;
  padding-right: 0.5%;
  padding-left: 0.5%;
}

.leftcontent {
  background-color: rgba(210,238,252,1);
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 85%;
  top: 0px;
  position: relative;
  border-left-color: rgba(205,205,205,1);
  padding-right: 0.5%;
  padding-left: 0.5%;
}

.rightcontent {
  background-color: rgba(51,177,236,1);
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 15%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  /* [disabled]margin-right: 0.3%; */
}

.footer {
 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="topimage">
    Top Image
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="list">
      <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="leftcontent">
      <h1>Home page</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="rightcontent">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what part is being shifted. I also see no red.

Comment: same here - no red, no shifting

Comment: I have edited the code. The background color of site is black. You can see the top image holder div (gray) along with other divs shifted slightly downwards. However, the solution below solved the problem. But i am not sure how come the margin of the list is responsible for shifting down of entire wrapper div

Answer (score 2):

It's [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing):

> If there is no border, padding, inline content, or clearance to separate the `margin-top` of a block from the `margin-top` of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, `height`, `min-height`, or `max-height` to separate the `margin-bottom` of a block from the `margin-bottom` of its last child, then those margins collapse. **The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.**

In your example, you have `.topimage` set to absolute position which makes it out of the normal content flow. The default top margin of the sibling `ul` collapses outside `.wrapper`.

To fix that, you can either reset the default top margin of the `ul`:

```
.list {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Or, add `overflow:auto` to the parent container `div`.

```
.wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: yes, that did it. Can you please explain why it happens? And in what way the top margin of the list is responsible for shifting down the entire wrapper div?

Comment: @pure_coder so does the updated answer explains it? I also edited your question to make it clearer for future visitors.